# (Spring) Can I use dependency injection inside a loop?

Tags: java, spring, for-loop, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application that allows users to save categories into a database. I can get my code to "work", however, I think it limits the amount of testing I can do, hence my question.

The controller receives a list of categories. The controller iterates over these categories, validates them and depending on whether they are valid, they are saved to a database. The controller finally returns a list of messages, such that the recipient can identify which category has been accepted or rejected, etc.

I have a list of model messages (List), which upon each iteration, the controller instantiates a new model message (new ModelMessage()) and eventually adds it to the List. **Is there a way to inject a new ModelMessage upon each iteration or do I need to use the new keyword**? If I do use the new keyword, I feel like this is limiting my testability/tightly coupling my controller to the model message.

The controller:

```
@PostMapping("/category")
    public String saveCategoryModelToDatabase(@RequestBody CategoryModelWrapper categoryModelWrapper){
        List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList = categoryModelWrapper.getCategoryModelList();
        modelMessageList.clear();

        for(CategoryModel categoryModel : categoryModelList){
            //Resetting model
            modelMessage = new ModelMessage(); //This tightly couples my method to the ModelMessage class, which is bad for testing?
            //@Autowired modelMessage; <-- something like this? Inject a new ModelMessage with each iteration.
            modelMessage.setName(categoryModel.getName());

            //Resetting categoryModelErrors
            Errors categoryModelErrors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(categoryModel, "categoryModel");
            categoryModelValidator.validate(categoryModel, categoryModelErrors);


            if(categoryModelErrors.hasErrors()){
                modelMessage.setStatus(ModelMessageStatusEnum.REJECTED);
                modelMessage.setReason(MODEL_MESSAGE_0004);
            }

            if(categoryModelService.save(categoryModel)){
                modelMessage.setStatus(ModelMessageStatusEnum.ACCEPTED);
            }
            else{
                modelMessage.setStatus(ModelMessageStatusEnum.REJECTED);
                modelMessage.setReason(MODEL_MESSAGE_0005);
            }
            modelMessageList.add(modelMessage);
        }

        return gson.toJson(modelMessageList);
    }
```

An example of the response to the recipient:

```
[{"name":"Arts","status":"ACCEPTED"},{"name":"Business","status":"ACCEPTED"},{"name":"Gaming","status":"ACCEPTED"},{"name":"Deals","status":"REJECTED","reason":"Category rejected because of an unexpected exception, i.e. possibly due to duplicate keys."}]
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Lookup `scope="prototype"`. It's a feature of Spring.

Comment: Why do you think, that it's bad to create a ModelMessage within the controller? We are basically talking about data that you return here, not about controller or service classes (where tight coupling indeed would be bad for testing). If you want to test your method, you provide input parameters and then check, if the right ModelMessages are part of the response. One of the easiest testable methods i've seen.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ApplicationContext, assuming you have access to it, as a factory for ModelMessage. But, is that really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create new ModelMessages in your Controller, it's only a data object and not a service bean. 
A junit can check the result of the method.

But if you really want to use Spring, I would look at the FactoryBean...

Example:

```
public class ModelMessage {
  String name;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component
public class ModelMessageFactory implements FactoryBean<ModelMessage> {

  @Override
  public ModelMessage getObject() throws Exception {
    return new ModelMessage();
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return ModelMessage.class;
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig
public class ModelMessageFactoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private ModelMessageFactory messageFactory;

  @Test
  public void testGetObject() throws Exception {

    assertNotNull("Factory is null", messageFactory);
    IModelMessage modelMessage1 = messageFactory.getObject();
    IModelMessage modelMessage2 = messageFactory.getObject();

    assertNotEquals("error object is equal", System.identityHashCode(modelMessage1),
        System.identityHashCode(modelMessage2));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetObjectType() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(ModelMessage.class, messageFactory.getObjectType());
  }
}
```